# How to get filename which generated on another server with PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, filenames, file-transfer

First server has code which generate file and give new name it.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: filename="i_want_get_it.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile(ROOT.'/files/5548951235');
```

And on another server I want to get name of file (i_want_get_it.pdf in code). I can only get content of file with

```
file_get_contents('http://some_link.com?act=getfile&id=5548951235')
```

Comment: Please reduce the tabbing in your snippets to reduce horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `file_get_contents()`, you may use [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) to also get the header of the HTTP response.

Here is an example :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
var_dump($header);

?>
```

You will see the `Content-disposition` data.